# Selecting Concatenated Item In ListBox (part of report)

Tags: ms-access

I have a report with a listbox (which contains a concatenated field)

```
SELECT tbl_Employee.GID, tbl_Employee.Sname, tbl_Employee.Gname FROM tbl_Employee ORDER BY tbl_Employee.Sname, tbl_Employee.Gname;
```

I want to select one of the items of this listbox so that the value (GID) is taken over in textbox GID (which is used to fill `tbl_Report`)

But somehow I can't select Items in the `ListBox` in the report, 
Anyone have a clue to why this is happening?

Overview of used Tables is added below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, please google Tutorial Using Listbox or combobox in Access. This is basic Access function, so there a tons of tutorials out there here which should not be repeated here. YOu can also use the access wizard

Comment: Downvoted: Question referes to report, but is in fact form. Question is unclear.

Comment: sorry for asking, but I'm quite a beginner, and there's an jungle of information to find,
but it's hard to find the matching information regarding my quest ....
:(

Comment: Do not worry or feel sorry, there are a lot of beginners here. It is not about the question itself, it is on the one hand, you have written later it is a form, not a report: **So edit your question!** Nobody wants to read through all the answer to find out a Form is meant. On the other hand (But not the reason for downvote), _I can't select Items_ is also not clear and to broad. Please read the in the help section how to write good questions and edit your Question appropriately. For Example: How do I use the Listbox to write data into a table?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Selectable Listboxes are not meant for reports, but you can use it in forms.

Comment: Then a) Edit your question please and b) What does  _I can't select Items in the ListBox_ mean? Does a click on an Item not respond? Or are you not able to seperate the GID from the String? Another idea: Have you considered using a combobox instead of a ListBox?

Comment: I made a form to fill in the field RTS_a, RDate & GID and put in in table tbl_Report.

GID should be taken from a concatenated field in ListBox 
concatenated field contains : GID, Sname, Gname from table tbl_Employee

I've tried also ComboBox, but seems to give the same result (Click does not respond) as in previous mentioned 
ListBox 
can this have to do with combination of options in Property Sheet ?